# Cannot follow Shortcuts in CIFS-mounted windows shares

Tags: linux, mount, shortcuts, samba, cifs

I have a windows share:

```
\\MYSERVER\SHARE\
                 MyFolder
                 MyShortcut\
                            SubFolder1
                            Subfolder2
```

Using a windows box, I can navigate through the shortcut to reach the subfolders.

But using a linux box with CentOS release 6.5, I can not navigate through the shortcut.

I have the following in my fstab:

```
//MYSERVER/SHARE /mnt/g cifs    uid=ME,gid=ME,noauto,credentials=/home/ME/.smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777   0 0
```

I can cd to /mnt/g and /mnt/g/MyFolder
but cannot cd to /mnt/g/MyShortcut

In /mnt/g, if I typed: cd MyShortcut:

```
-bash: cd: MyShortcut: Invalid argument
```

If I typed: ls -l

```
drwx--x--x. 2 ME ME 0    Apr 17 12:16 MyShortcut
drwxrwxrwx. 1 ME ME 4096 Sep 19  2013 MyFolder
```

Update: I also tried to mount \MYSERVER\SHARE\MyShortcut from fstab, but ended with errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Windows implements its shortcuts as `.lnk` files (typically you don't see the `.lnk` extension as it's one of the few extensions that remains hidden even if you tell the Folder Settings control panel to display them).  When you use shortcuts in Windows, these files are read by `explorer.exe` to change the current folder when navigating through folders.

Many Linux filesystems feature [symlinks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link) which do the same thing, but work on the filesystem level and thus independent of any program.  Windows-style `.lnk` shortcuts are not supported by the file manager you are using (probably `nautilus`).

The reason why the `cd` command is failing is because you are asking Linux to `cd` to a file and not a directory/folder.

Some workarounds:

- The `.lnk` file is just a text file, so you can open it in `gedit` or `vi` and path manually to its equivalent CIFS destination.
- Windows supports UNIX/Linux-style symlinks with the `mklink` command (on NTFS filesystems) - however I haven't tried accessing them via CIFS share to see if they'd work.

Comment: Thanks, I checked the path of the ".lnk" and directly mounted it.